# How to optimize the scenario of getting a random picture?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have about 100 pages, every of which has 10-100 images attached. The path to the images are kept in a database.

Then, I have an area at every page where user can see random pictures from the list of pictures mentioned above. This image changes every 3 seconds.

To archieve such scenario I use a javascript function, which calls itself every 3 seconds.

```
function GenerateNewImg() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl.php",
        type : "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        async:true,
        success: function(data){
            $("#imgtochange").attr("src", data.res);
        }
    });

    t = setTimeout('GenerateNewImg()',3000);
}
```

And in myurl.php I randomly choose a page and then an image.

I think, this is not very good solution, because it consumes processor time at the server.

Are there better ways to get a behaviour I need?

Comment: As a side note, please use `setTimeout(GenerateNewImg, 3000)`. You should not pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Represent your file list as JSON, load it in its own script block so it can be cached on the browser. Then read the data from a random position in the dataset. This way you don't have to keep going back to the server.

Comment: So I should create a file list once (maybe updating it with cron instructions) and store it on the server in .js format. Did I understand you right?

Comment: @Dmitry Korolev No, that is not what he meant.  He means for you to send a JSON file to the browser.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for more information on JSON.

Comment: @Levi Morrison But this way the file will be created for every user. Even for the same user, if he reloads a page.

Comment: @Dmitry Korolev Not if you use caching.

Comment: @Levi Morrison Please exuse my persistence, but can you explain why my ajax request to the server will not be executed if I cache JSON result at a client side?

Comment: If you cache on the client you get a "304 not modified" from the AJAX  request, so the browser gives you back the SAME file instead of downloading it again.

Comment: To avoid AJAX cache, many use "salt" - a random number added as a parameter to break the cache. I like to use the current timestamp for this purpose.